# Python code works 20 times slower than Java. Is there a way to speed up Python?

Tags: java, python, performance

I wrote a program in Python and in Java to search for the smallest integer solution of the equation:

a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5=e^5  (expected output is 133^5+110^5+84^5+27^5=144^5)

Powers and roots are either computed directly ("direct calculation" method) or computed and stored in an array ("power lookup" method). Fifth powers are looked up like n5 = fifth_power[n]. Fifth power root is computed using a binary search in array 'fifth_power`.

I am running it on NetBeans if it matters. It takes:

```
30. s (Python, direct)
20. s (Python, lookup)
5.6 s (Java, direct)
0.8 s (Java, lookup)
```

Is there a way to boost Python performance? I am not looking for better math (sieving of some kind). I am looking for better implementation of "for each combination of a,b,c,d compute some of their powers, check if the sum is a perfect power. If it is - print the result".

Is it expected that Python runs some 20 times slower than Java?

Python 3.5

http://pastebin.com/qVthWGKm

```
from array import *
import math
import time

#PYTHON, BRUTEFORCE : ~30 s
millis1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
keep_searching = True
a=1
result=""
while(keep_searching):
    a+=1
    for b in range(1,a+1):
        for c in range(1,b+1):
            for d in range(1,c+1):
                sum=math.pow(a,5)+math.pow(b,5)+math.pow(c,5)+math.pow(d,5)
                root = math.pow(sum,0.2)
                e = round(root)


                e5 = math.pow(e,5)              

                if(e5==sum):
                    result="{}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 = {}^5".format(int(a),int(b), int(c),int(d), int(e))
                    keep_searching = False
                    millis2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print(result)
print("Found solution in {} ms".format(millis2-millis1))

#PYTHON, PRECOMPUTE POWERS: ~20 s
millis3 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))  
#fifth_power #175 is enough
size=176
fifth_power = [None] * size
for i in range(size):
    fifth_power[i]=long(math.pow(i,5))

millis4 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))  

#returns  value if it is a perfect power (32 returns 2)  
#returns -1 if between perfect powers, -2 if greater than max value in array, -3 if smaller than min value in array

def check_perfect_power(number, min, max, fifth_power):


    current=int((min+max)/2)
    while(max>=min):
        if(number==fifth_power[current]):
            return current
        elif(number>fifth_power[current]):
            min=current+1
            current=int((max+min)/2)
        else:
            max=current-1
            current=int((max+min)/2)

    if(min>=len(fifth_power)):        
        return -2
    if(max<0):
        return -3

    return -1  

keep_searching = True
a=0
result=""
while(keep_searching):
    a+=1
    for b in range(1,a+1):
        for c in range(1,b+1):
            for d in range(1,c+1):
                mymax=min(int(a*1.32)+1, size-1)
                e=check_perfect_power(fifth_power[a]+fifth_power[b]+fifth_power[c]+fifth_power[d], a, mymax, fifth_power)
                if(e>0):
                    result="{}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 = {}^5".format(int(a),int(b), int(c),int(d), int(e))
                    keep_searching = False
                    millis5 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print(result)

    print("Populated in {} ms, find solution in {} ms".format(millis4-millis3,millis5-millis4))
```

Java 8:

http://pastebin.com/G4V3fHnD

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Eu514 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       bruteforce();  //Solution found by bruteforce in 5600 ms.
       prepopulate(); //Solution found by prepopulation in 761 ms.
    }    

    public static void bruteforce(){ //JAVA BRUTEFORCE        
        Long t2 = 0L;
        Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();    
        boolean keepSearching = true;
        int a = 0;
        long e = 0;
        String solution = "";

        while (keepSearching) {
            a++;
            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
                for (int c = 1; c <= b; c++) {
                    for (int d = 1; d <= c; d++) {
                        long sum = (long) (Math.pow(a, 5) + Math.pow(b, 5) + Math.pow(c, 5) + Math.pow(d, 5)); //sum=a^5+b^5+c^5+d^5

                        e = Math.round(Math.pow(sum, 0.2)); //e= sum^(1/5), rounded
                        long e5 = (long) Math.pow(e,5);    //e^5

                        if(e5==sum){
                            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            solution = a + "^5 + " + b + "^5 + " + c + "^5 + " + d + "^5 = " + e + "^5";
                            keepSearching = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        long delta = ((t2-t1));
        System.out.println(solution+"\nSolution found by bruteforce in "+delta+" ms.");    
    }

    public static void prepopulate(){  //JAVA PREPOPULATE
        Long t2 = 0L;
        Long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int size = 176;
        long[] powers = populatePowers(size);

        boolean keepSearching = true;
        int a = 0;
        int e = 0;
        String solution = "";

        while (keepSearching) {
            a++;
            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
                for (int c = 1; c <= b; c++) {
                    for (int d = 1; d <= c; d++) {
                        long sum = powers[a] + powers[b] + powers[c] + powers[d];
                        int max = (int) Math.min(size - 1, (a * 1.32 + 1));
                        e = checkIfPerfectPower(sum, a, max, powers);
                        if (e > 0) {
                            t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            solution = a + "^5 + " + b + "^5 + " + c + "^5 + " + d + "^5 = " + e + "^5";
                            keepSearching = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        long delta = ((t2-t1));
        System.out.println(solution+"\nSolution found by prepopulation in "+delta+" ms.");
    }

    public static long[] populatePowers(int max){
        long[] powers = new long[max];
        for (int i = 0; i < powers.length; i++) {
            powers[i]=(long) Math.pow(i,5);
        }        
        return powers;
    }

    public static int checkIfPerfectPower(long number, int min, int max, long[] arr){
        int current =((min+max)/2);
        while(max>=min){
            if(number==arr[current]){
                return current;
            }else if(number>arr[current]){
                min = current + 1;
                current = (max + min) / 2;                
            }else{
                max=current-1;
                current=(max+min)/2;
            }
        }
        if(min>=arr.length) return -2;
        if(max<0) return -3;
        return -1;              
    }  

}
```

Comment: You could start by replace every instance of `math.pow(x,y)` with `x**y`.

Comment: You could also try running it with jython and/or pypy.

Comment: That's actually a much better showing on Python's side than I expected, considering CPython has no JIT and dynamic lookup for almost everything.

Comment: And delete the binary lookup, build a `set()` instead to check for `e`'s membership in `fifth_powers`.

Comment: You're also computing the powers in the innermost loop, when things like `math.pow(a,5)` won't change, so moving those to just inside their respective loops offers an easy step to improve matters. (saves about 10s for me)

Comment: For java, i'd try `long pow5(long x) { long a = x*x; long b = a*a; return x*b; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
from array import *
import time
import numpy as np

#PYTHON, BRUTEFORCE : ~30 s
millis1 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
keep_searching = True
a = 1
result = ""
while(keep_searching):
    a += 1
    a_pow = a ** 5
    for b in xrange(1, a+1):
        b_pow = b ** 5
        for c in xrange(1, b+1):
            c_pow = c ** 5
            for d in xrange(1, c+1):
                d_pow = d ** 5
                sum_pow = a_pow + b_pow + c_pow + d_pow
                root = sum_pow ** 0.2
                e = round(root)


                e5 = e ** 5             

                if(e5 == sum_pow):
                    result="{}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 + {}^5 = {}^5".format(a, b, c, d, e)
                    keep_searching = False
                    millis2 = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

print(result)
print("Found solution in {} ms".format(millis2-millis1))
```

Python 2.7, with some code optimizations

133^5 + 110^5 + 84^5 + 27^5 = 144.0^5
Found solution in 8333 ms

It could be a little different from CPU to CPU.

Answer (score 1):

What about improving the java code?

```
int size = 200;
long[] pow5 = new long[size];

for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i)
{
    long sqr = i * i;
    pow5[i] = sqr * sqr * i;
}

for (int a = 1; a < size; ++a)
{
    for (int b = 1; b <= a; ++b)
    {
        for (int c = 1; c <= b; ++c)
        {
            int e = a + 1;
            for (int d = 1; d <= c; ++d)
            {
                long sum = pow5[a] + pow5[b] + pow5[c] + pow5[d];
                while(pow5[e] < sum){ e++; }
                if (pow5[e] == sum)
                {
                    System.out.println(a + "^5 + " + b + "^5 + " + c + "^5 + " + d + "^5 = " + e + "^5");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```